# ajax [file 1] -> php [file 2] -> $_POST [file 1]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a budget application with HTML, Javascript, and PHP. My goal is to have the user be able to add data into a database from a form provided. I already have a ton of php at the top of my 'dashboard.php' (which contains the form) so I didn't want to run dashboard.php on submit, so instead I created a button that preforms an AJAX call to a different php file 'addIncome.php'.

I have two different files...

dashboard.php &
addincome.php

dashboard.php contains my form, as well as my javascript to run an AJAX call.

addincome.php is using $_POST to grab the values from the form in dashboard.php and make a mysqli_query. However, at first nothing was happening so I decided to echo the value of one of the return values from my $_POST. And ended up getting this error...

```
undefined index iName in addIncome.php
undefined index iAmount in addIncome.php
```

So from there I though that maybe I didn't have access to the dashboard.php by default so I included...

```
include('dashboard.php');
```

Still no difference...

I'm really at a stand still here. Any thoughts?

Thanks

The form...

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="iName" placeholder="income name">
    <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="iAmount" placeholder="amount">
    <input type="date" name="iDate">
</form>
```

The javascript...

```
<script>
    $('.in-btn').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "addIncome.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: 'show=content',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.in-btn').html(data);    
            }
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            // location.reload(); 
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

The php...

```
<?php

    echo "adding...";

    require_once('connection.php');
    include('dashboard.php');

    $iUser = $_SESSION["username"];
    $iName = $_POST["iName"];
    $iAmount = $_POST["iAmount"];

    echo $iName;

    $sql = "INSERT INTO income (user, name, amount, date) VALUE ('pmanke', '$iName', '$iAmount','1/16/19')";
    mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending any post data with your AJAX call except for:
`show=content`. You want to send your form data. You can retrieve your form data with:

```
$("#id-of-form").serialize()
```

That way your PHP code is able to retrieve the correct values from your POST data.

An even more general way to do this is to just create a normal form with a submit button and an action and use javascript to catch the submit event and make an AJAX call instead:

HTML:

```
<form id="idForm" action="addIncome.php">
    <input type="text" name="iName" placeholder="income name">
    <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" name="iAmount" placeholder="amount">
    <input type="date" name="iDate">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
     });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Comment: Got it thanks @Laurens! I came across some research that was saying I could use anything in the data field, which made me not even question if that was a problem. Also, I am seeing that the form you drafted calls upon addIncome.php directly, so does that mean that I don't have to make an AJAX call? I really don't need anything from the file (data wise) to be returned, I just need to make an SQL query. With the action set to my PHP script and using the serialize method wouldn't I be okay?